# max(sum(field query in Hive/SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with lots of transactions for users across a month.

I need to take the hour from each day where Sum(cost) is at its highest.

I've tried MAX(SUM(Cost)) but get an error.

How would I go about doing this please?

**here is some sample data**

```
+-------------+------+----------+------+
|   user id   | hour |   date   | Cost |
+-------------+------+----------+------+
|      343252 |   13 | 20170101 | 21.5 |
|    32532532 |   13 | 20170101 | 22.5 |
|    35325325 |   13 | 20170101 | 30.5 |
|   325325325 |   13 | 20170101 | 10   |
|    64643643 |   12 | 20170101 | 22   |
|   643643643 |   12 | 20170101 | 31   |
|   436325234 |   13 | 20170101 | 15   |
|   213213213 |   13 | 20170101 | 12   |
| 53265436436 |   17 | 20170101 | 19   |
+-------------+------+----------+------+
```

**Expected Output:**

I need just one row per day, where it shows the total cost from the 'most expensive' hour. In this case, 13:00 had a total cost of 111.5

[image]

Comment: Supply a data sample including required results

Comment: Thank you for your response - I have added that info :)

Comment: (1) Better, but please add it as text so it could be copied. (2) What do you want to do in a case of a tie between hours?

Comment: I've copied and pasted as text - but I didn't see a way to add it as a table, so it's not very readable - if you know how to make it a table that'll be great. In terms of ties between hours, that is extremely unlikely to happen. However, if it did, I am not too worried which one get's printed

Comment: (1) https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ (2) ctrl+k

Comment: P.s. Use only the ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: it looks like it's pasted OK now - the date format is yyyymmdd - unfortunately we have around 10 billion lines of data, so I can't change that

Comment: On the contrary. Change it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
select      hr
           ,dt
           ,total_cost

from       (select      dt
                       ,hr
                       ,sum(cost)   as total_cost
                       ,row_number () over
                        (
                            partition by    dt
                            order by        sum(cost) desc
                        ) as rn

            from        mytable
            group by    dt,hr
            ) t

where       rn = 1
```

---

```
+----+------------+------------+
| hr |     dt     | total_cost |
+----+------------+------------+
| 13 | 2017-01-01 | 111.5      |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
select AVG(hour) as 'Hour',date as 'Date',sum(cost) as 'TotalCost' from dbo.Table_3 group by date
```